# ios Keyboard must not show up automatically for a UITextField in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uialertcontroller

I am trying to show UIAlertController with text field.  When it launches keyfoard automatically shows up as textfield get the focus automatically.  How can I show alert with textfield without keyboard (it should show up only when user clicks on textfield).

Here is my code

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Collect Input"    message:@"input message"
    preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Submit" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
        //use alert.textFields[0].text
    }];
    UIAlertAction* cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    //cancel action
    }];
    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {
         // A block for configuring the text field prior to displaying the alert
         //[textField resignFirstResponder];

    }];
    [alert addAction:defaultAction];
    [alert addAction:cancelAction];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind would be to setUserInteractionEnabled = false in the configuration handler and immediately do a dispatch_async() to re-enable it.  Failing that, a dispatch_async() that resign the first responder

Comment: A text field/text view shows the keyboard when it becomes the **first responder**. Most likely, the alert controller is causing that as a result of being presented. You could disable user interaction temporarily like @ekscripto suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions.

1. You can get a reference to the text field in the `addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler` callback and store it in a local variable. Then in the completion handler of `presentViewController` you can call `resignFirstResponder` on the text field. But this solution is far from ideal because the keyboard will appear and then immediately be dismissed.
2. Better yet is to set the text field's `delegate` and implement the `shouldBeginEditing` delegate method. Add an instance variable to act as a flag. The first time `shouldBeginEditing` is called, not the flag isn't set, set it, and return `NO`. Then each time after, check the flag and return `YES`.

Here's the implementation for option 2:

Indicate that your class conforms to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol in the .m file:

```
@interface YourClassHere () <UITextFieldDelegate>
@end
```

Add an instance variable for the flag:

```
BOOL showKeyboard = NO;
```

Update your alert setup code to set the text field's delegate:

```
[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {
    textField.delegate = self;
}];
```

Implement the text field delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (showKeyboard) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        showKeyboard = YES;
        return NO;
    }
}
```

This prevents the initial display of the keyboard but allows it any time after that.